# Hello, I've been trying to create a trading signal for macd in R. I'm having difficulty generating the signal and the data frame that has the signals

Tags: r, quantmod

first, I imported the data into R using quantmod.

```
getSymbols("QQQ")
QQQ <- xts::last(QQQ, "1 year")

QQQ
```

then, I used the MACD function to get the MACD for my etf.

```
macd_QQQ <- MACD(QQQ[,"QQQ.Close"], nFast = 12, nSlow = 26, nSig = 9, percent = FALSE)

macd_QQQ
```

I also obtained the ADX.

```
adx_QQQ <- ADX(QQQ, n =14)
adx_QQQ
```

Then I specified which values of the overall functions I wanted

```
adx <- adx_QQQ$ADX
adx

macd <- macd_QQQ$macd
macd
```

Currently, I am stuck here

```
macd_indicator <- function(macd)
if (macd > 0) {
  signal <- "buy"
} else {
  signal <- "sell"
}
```

The code has no problem running, but I am confused as to why buy and sell signals are not being produced in accordance with the values of macd.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't bet my money on this though.

```
library(tidyquant) # It uses Quantmod
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

tq_get("QQQ", from = today() %m-% years(1)) %>%
  tq_mutate(select = close,
            mutate_fun = MACD) %>%
  mutate(signal = if_else(macd > 0, "BUY", "SELL")) %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  aes(x = date, y = close, col = signal) + 
  geom_point() + 
  theme_light()
```

[image]

Comment: "I wouldn't bet my money on this, though" made my day. It seems the model is a good indicator on when to buy _put options_.